# how to convert a named datatable to json using json.net

Tags: json

I need to Serialize\Deserialze between DataTable and json using json.net.

I found that json.net igrone the "TableName" Attribute.how can i add it?

code like this.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.TableName = "TestTable";
table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
var dr = table.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 1;
dr["name"] = "foo";
table.Rows.Add(dr);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

when Serialize, got json [{"id":1,"name":"foo"}]. this json does not have TableName,and Deserialize it , the table also haven't TableName.

so,I need the TableName ,how can i hold it?

Comment: in the json.net sourcecode there are some code for read tablename,but i can;t find how to write it into json .if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
      {
        dt = new DataTable((string)reader.Value);
        reader.Read();
      }
      else
      {
        dt = new DataTable();
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a custom DataTable converter for JSON.NET that does this. Grab the source from here: https://github.com/chris-herring/DataTableConverter

Use it like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, new Serialization.DataTableConverter());
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json, new Serialization.DataTableConverter());
```

It serializes/deserializes a System.Data.DataTable in this format:

```
{
    "TableName": "TestTable",
    "Columns": [
        {
            "AllowDBNull": false,
            "AutoIncrement": true,
            "AutoIncrementSeed": 2,
            "AutoIncrementStep": 1,
            "Caption": "PrimaryKey",
            "ColumnName": "PrimaryKey",
            "DataType": "Int32",
            "DateTimeMode": "UnspecifiedLocal",
            "DefaultValue": null,
            "MaxLength": -1,
            "Ordinal": 0,
            "ReadOnly": false,
            "Unique": true
        }
    ],
    "Rows": [
        [
            1
        ],
        [
            2
        ],
        [
            3
        ]
    ],
    "PrimaryKey": ["PrimaryKey"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks... it is use full.